# what mean the error local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, model, django-templates

i am trying to get values from the views.py function into the html template but the  system crash and display this error :

> local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment

## views.py

```
def update(request,pk):
    #deny anonymouse user to enter the  detail page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            instance = get_object_or_404(suspect,pk=pk)
            print(suspect)
        context = {
        "title":instance.suspect_name,
        "instance":instance,
      }
        return render(request,'blog/update.html',context)
```

## update.html

```
{{instance.id}}
```

its just a test because what i want is to be able to **update form** based on the **id**  so i am trying to get the id of the object.

i will appreciate any help

Comment: that you *use* a variable before you have given it a value. For example if `request.method == 'POST'` fails, then `instance` is never set, but you still use it in `context = { ... }`.

Comment: so you mean is not write the write if request.method == 'POST' ?

Answer (score 0):

If the `if` conditions fails then `instance` variable will not be available and hence it's giving error **`local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment`**.

To avoid that, you can define the **`context`** dict first and then update value inside.

**views.py**

```
def update(request,pk):
    context = {}
    #deny anonymouse user to enter the  detail page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            instance = get_object_or_404(suspect,pk=pk)
            print(suspect)
            context.update ({"title":instance.suspect_name, "instance":instance})

        return render(request,'blog/update.html',context)
```

**HTML**

Check if **`instance`** is present and then show.

```
{% if instance %}
    {{instance.id}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @DjangoDg, Yeah, if the `if request.method == "POST"` fails it will be empty. That's the expected result.

Comment: but why it the if statement fails it must  be a POST method

Comment: i have another question can you help me with it ?? about the update function using ajax call

Answer (score 0):

it means you try to use `instance`, but it is unknown because it never get past one of the `if statements`, possibly because user was not logged in or because requestmethod is not `POST`.

This would fix it:

```
def update(request,pk):
    #deny anonymouse user to enter the  detail page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login")

    if request.method == "POST":
        instance = get_object_or_404(suspect,pk=pk)
        print(suspect)
        context = {
           "title":instance.suspect_name,
           "instance":instance,
         } 
    else:
        context = {}
    return render(request,'blog/update.html',context)
```

(I removed your `else` statement, becuase it does not make much sense there )

Answer (score 0):

Its because request.method may not be "POST", so add condition to your code:

update.html

```
{% if instance %} 
{{instance.id}}
{% endif %}
```